# Send a file as multipart through XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets, file-upload, multipart

Can I send a file as multipart by [XMLHttpRequest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to a servlet?

I am making a form and submitting it as multipart, but somehow I am not getting a response for successfully uploading it. I do not want the page to be refreshed, so it has to take place by Ajax.

Comment: See also: [Sending images from Canvas elements using Ajax and PHP $_FILES](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5303242/938089?sending-images-from-canvas-elements-using-ajax-and-php-files)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

That's only possible with the XHR [`FormData` API](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-formdata) (previously known being part of as "XHR2" or "XHR Level 2", currently known as "XHR Advanced Features").

Given this HTML,

```html
<input type="file" id="myFileField" name="myFile" />
```

you can upload it as below:

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("myFile", document.getElementById("myFileField").files[0]);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "myServletUrl");
xhr.send(formData);
```

XHR will take care about proper headers and request body encoding and the file will in this example be available on the server side as `form-data` part with the name `myFile`.

You need to keep in mind that `FormData` API is not supported in older browsers. At [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=xhr2) you can see that it's currently implemented in Chrome 7+, Firefox 3.5+, Safari 5+, Internet Explorer 10+ and [Opera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) 12+.

In case you're using jQuery, then you might be tempted to use its `$.val()` function as below:

```js
formData.append("myFile", $("#myFileField").val());
```

But this is incorrect as it doesn't return the whole [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) object, but merely the file name as `String` which is utterly useless as it doesn't contain the file contents.

If you don't want to use `document.getElementById()` for some reason, then use one of the following instead:

```js
formData.append("myFile", $("#myFileField").prop("files")[0]);
```

```js
formData.append("myFile", $("#myFileField")[0].files[0]);
```

An alternative is to use the [jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). Your entire form, when written and functioning properly without any line of JavaScript code, will then instantly be ajaxified with just the following line:

```
$("#formId").ajaxForm(function(response) {
    // Handle Ajax response here.
});
```

It also supports file uploads as well by a hidden iframe trick. See also [this jQuery Form documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) for an in-depth explanation. You may only need to change the servlet code to be able to intercept on both normal (synchronous) and Ajax (asynchronous) requests. See also this answer for a concrete example: *[Simple calculator with JSP/Servlet and Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114742/simple-calculator-in-jsp/4115298#4115298)*

Either way, the uploaded file should then be available in the `doPost()` method of a [`@MultipartConfig`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html) servlet as follows:

```
Part myFile = request.getPart("myFile");
```

Or if you're still on Servlet 2.5 or older, use Apache Commons FileUpload the usual way. See also this answer for a concrete example: *[How can I upload files to a server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)*

Comment: And what happen if in our page we generate automatically many input files ? can we generate IDs ?

Comment: @BalusC I'm wondering why there is no info about how & why XMLHttpRequest + FormData sets headers automatically, on MDN or other places (googled a lot). Whenever I set `Content-type', 'multipart/form-data'` my requests fail, but works if headers are not specified. But why?

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` works, but how to do the same with `axios`?

Comment: Doesn't work in my case

Comment: Click the 'Ask Question' button on right top to get answer on that.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to send `multipart/form-data` with XMLHttpRequest (though it is possible in modern browsers, with `XHR2`. See [BalusC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395911/send-a-file-as-multipart-through-xmlhttprequest/9397172#9397172)).

A common way to achieve what you want is to use a regular `form`, but in an `iframe` instead. This way, only the `iframe` is refreshed on upload.

Comment: Actually I want a response whether the file is uploaded or not.
Also, I want the location where the image is uploaded.

Comment: Tejasva: Look at the example from Napolux, it specifies how you can call a js function on the parent window when upload is complete. It could provide the image location as well.

Comment: @LinusGThiel It is possible. See BalusC's answer.

Comment: Yes, it's possible with XHR2. With modern browsers, there is also FileAPI and other cool features. Perhaps I should try to explain how to accomplish this, with fallbacks for older browsers, etc. Honestly, I wasn't sure I would get that across in a good manner to the asker. I agree that BalusC's answer is better than mine.