# HTML5 FormData returns null in Java Servlet request.getParameter()

Tags: ajax, html, servlets, xmlhttprequest, form-data

My view is HTML 5. I'm using FormData to make a AJAX 2 POST to a Servlet. Inside the servlet i'm trying to read request parameters. I can't see any parameters. However, Google Chrome Dev console shows the request payload. How can I get the same in Servlet code? Any help will be appreciated. Here's the code.

JS code

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('firstName', 'ABC');
formData.append('lastName', 'XYZ');

xhr.open("POST", targetLocation, true);
xhr.send(formData);
```

Servlet code (both parameters return `null`)

```
out.println("Hello! "+ request.getParameter("firstName")+ " "+ request.getParameter("lastName")+ ", thanks for sending your feedback." );
```

Google Chrome Console

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="firstName"
XYZ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="lastName"
ABC
```

Comment: Provide some more code of doPost() method of Servlet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The HTML5 `FormData` API sends a `multipart/form-data` request. It's initially designed to be able to upload files by ajax, with the new version 2 `XMLHttpRequest`. Uploading files wasn't possible with the previous version.

The [`request.getParameter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29) by default recognizes `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests only. But you're sending a `multipart/form-data` request. You need to annotate your servlet class with [`@MultipartConfig`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/MultipartConfig.html) so that you can get them by `request.getParameter()`.

```
@WebServlet
@MultipartConfig
public class YourServlet extends HttpServlet {}
```

Or, when you're still not on Servlet 3.0 yet, use Apache Commons FileUpload. For a more detailed answer on both approaches, see this: [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

If you don't need to upload files at all, use the "standard" `XMLHttpRequest` approach instead.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var data = "firstName=" + encodeURIComponent(firstName)
        + "&lastName=" + encodeURIComponent(lastName);
xhr.open("POST", targetLocation, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(data);
```

This way you don't need `@MultipartConfig` on your servlet anymore.

#### See also:

- [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)
- [sending a file as multipart through xmlHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395911/sending-a-file-as-multipart-through-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: HI Balus, Thanks for the post. Your answer was accurate and to the point.

FormData is an overkill for my simple app. I think I'm better off with the simple XMLHttpRequest.

But, I've a simple question, how do I send request parameters with xhr?  I know there's a method called send() which takes input. How do I use it?

Comment: Construct an URL encoded query string. E.g. `"name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3"` and pass it to `send()`. However, much easier is to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com). This saves you from writing XMLHttpRequest boilerplate yourself (and worrying about cross browser problems). See also the doc and examples: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Yes I got it. It's working . I like jQuery Framework because it can handle lot of  boilerplate, as you mentioned. But, using jQuery how do I check something like this:
 if (typeof xhr.withCredentials === undefined) {
        // do something
    } else {
//do something else
 }
Since I don't have a xhr handle?

Comment: Thanks, great explanation :)