# HTTP Post Request with Image Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, http, post, cloudsight

I am trying to submit an Post Request to an image recognition API using Javascript, but I cannot work out how to send the actual image. I know that I cannot send it just using a local file (I get the "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes" error when I try to run it). How would I send the image using a Post request?

My code so far is:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open("POST", "cigarette.jpg", false);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "CloudSight [key]");

xhr.send("http://api.cloudsightapi.com/image_requests");

console.log(xhr.status);
console.log(xhr.statusText);
```

I am quite new to Javascript and APIs and haven't really done anything like this before; how would I send the image without going into incredibly complicated stuff?

Comment: It depends on what format the service expects the data to be in (and I have no idea what that appears to be since they don't seem to link to any public facing documentation from [their API homepage](http://cloudsightapi.com/api)). Oh, no, found the docs, they are just well hidden by a link (that doesn't look like a link) in the middle of the page.

Comment: (The second argument of `open` should be the URL of the webservice's endpoint though).

Comment: So [it says](https://cloudsight.readme.io/) "Image attached as a multipart-form-request part.", which means you just post form data in the regular way.

Comment: Duplicate of [sending a file as multipart through xmlHttpRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395911/sending-a-file-as-multipart-through-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: @Quentin So if the second argument of open is the URL, where does the image go, and how would I attach form data? Sorry if this is really basic stuff... is there a link I can look at to tell me about it perhaps? EDIT: sorry, posted before I saw the link: thanks a lot! :)

Comment: See the duplicate question.

Comment: You are sending a post request to the image....not the service.... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with your code.

1. You need correct HTTP headers to port the image.
2. You cannot POST a JPG image like that.

Further you are not using the API properly, kindly take a look here to see how to do it.

https://cloudsight.readme.io/docs/testinput

Also find a sample here in curl

```
curl -i -X POST \
-H "Authorization: CloudSight [key]" \
-F "image_request[image]=@Image.jpg" \
-F "image_request[locale]=en-US" \
https://api.cloudsightapi.com/image_requests
```

Comment: Thanks, I will: when you say correct HTTP headers to port the image, what do you mean?

Comment: You need to set a HTTP Header `Authorization: CloudSight [key]` and `multipart/form-data` is also needed which cannot be done with regular `xhr`. You might want to switch to jQuery to do it in a better way.