# Asana API - upload files using Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery-file-upload, asana, asana-api

I have a project that requires file uploads into Asana. I would like to be able to do  this through Asana's API if possible. I have been able to successfully create tasks in Asana using Ajax Post requests. Is there anyway to use an Ajax Post request to upload a file to an Asana task? I would like to be able to upload files straight from an HTML FileUplaod Object. Does anyone know if this is possible?

I have tried Posting an JSON object like this to the attachments API, but this did not work.

https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/{taskID}/attachments

{
    "parent": 1337,
    "download_url": "https://www.dropbox.com/s/1234567890abcdef/Screenshot.png?dl=1",
  }

I also don't want to post using a url, I want to post directly from the FileUpload object, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is to check out this other stack overflow question, which has a pretty good description of how to pull this off. [sending a file as multipart through xmlHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395911/sending-a-file-as-multipart-through-xmlhttprequest)

The long answer is this:

Uploading files has a different "feel" than most of the rest of our API, because the attachments endpoint expects to take content of `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`. There are several main things you have to get just right for this to work:

1. You have to set that Content-Type request header to `multipart/form-data` and to also in that header set the key `boundary` to be a unique, preferably long boundary to delimit the file, let's use `1z2x3c4v5b` for this example.
2. You start the upload's body with 2 dashes and the boundary, i.e. `--1z2x3c4v5b`, followed by a newline
3. Still in the upload *body*, after the delimiter you have to provide some "headers" specifying Content-Disposition and Content-Type correctly for the file (i.e. what type of image it is, what its name is, that sort of thing)
4. 2 newlines
5. The raw bytes of the file
6. 2 newlines
7. 2 dashes, the delimiter, and 2 final dashes, i.e. `--1z2x3c4v5b--`

Please note how all these features come together in the example in [our Attachments documentation](https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/attachments#upload). This song-and-dance, which has to be done *just right* is what the author of that other SO post meant with "XHR will take care about proper headers and request body encoding". You can attempt to pull this off yourself, but I would recommend the approach they outline because it's by far the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using the following code.

```
    function addAttachment(taskID)
        {
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append("file", document.getElementById("fileUploader").files[0]);

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
              if (this.readyState === 4) {
                console.log(this.responseText);
              }
            });

            xhr.open("POST", "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/"+taskID+"/attachments");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Bearer <access-token>");

            xhr.send(data);
        }
```