# bad content-type header, no multipart boundary

Tags: html

I'm trying to upload a file from my HTML page to my NodeJS backend

I get the error "bad content-type header, no multipart boundary" when choosing multipart/form-data as the content type.

form:

```
<form>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">File Upload</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Select File </th>
      <td><input id="csv" name="csv" type="file" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitClickEvt"/> 
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var submitClickEvt = document.getElementById('submitClickEvt');
        submitClickEvt.addEventListener('click', submitClicked);
           function submitClicked(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var data = document.getElementById('csv').value;


                ajaxCall(data, "http://localhost:3000/user/uploadpdf", function(status, response) {
                if (status == 200) {

                } else {
                    alert('Error', status)
                }
            });
          }

        function ajaxCall(data, url, callback) {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.open("POST", url, true);
            xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4) {
                    return callback(this.status, JSON.parse(xhttp.response));
                }
            }
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
            xhttp.send(data);
        }
</script>
```

I want to upload to the backend, but it seems to not be working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send a file as multipart through XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395911/send-a-file-as-multipart-through-xmlhttprequest)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a boundary when you use multipart/form-data, check boundary parameter in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

Your code is missing that and just setting content type so that seems to be a cause of the issue.