# How to upload a file as mulipart file to back-end using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-boot, java-ee-6

I'm new here! I'm trying to develop a microservice application to receive data (json or xml) and store it to database. I don't know how to link the front-end and back-end using javascript.

Here is my code for WordController:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile",
        method = RequestMethod.POST,
        consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)

public String fileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException
{
    File convertFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
    convertFile.createNewFile();

    try (FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(convertFile))
    {
        fout.write(file.getBytes());
    }
    catch (Exception exe)
    {
        exe.printStackTrace();
    }

     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     TypeReference<List<Word>> typeReference = new TypeReference<List<Word>>(){};

        try {

            List<Word> words = mapper.readValue(convertFile,typeReference);
            wordServiceFile.save(words);

            return ("Words saved!");

        } catch (IOException e){

            return ("Unable to save words: " + e.getMessage());

        }

}
```

and JS:

```
 function addListWords() {

  var data = document.getElementById('inputFile').files[0];

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
          console.log(this.responseText);
      }
  });

  xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/word/uploadFile");
  xhr.send(data);

}
```

and HTML code:

```
<!-- Add list of words -->
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <h2 class="font-weight-light">Add list of words </h2>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="FichierAdd">File</label>
                                    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="inputFile"><br>
                                    <button onclick="addListWords()" type="button" class="btn btn-success center-block" >Add List</button>
                                </div><br><br><br><br>
```

and I got this error:

{"timestamp":"2020-03-27T15:30:29.823+0000","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","message":"Content type 'application/json' not supported","trace":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/json' not supported\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:227)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:421)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:367)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:110)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.getHandlerInternal(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:59)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:395)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1234)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1016)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\r\n","path":"/word/uploadFile"}

**CAN SOMEONE HELP ME PLEAAASE!**

Comment: The back-end code works for me using Postman

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send a file as multipart through xmlHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395911/send-a-file-as-multipart-through-xmlhttprequest)

Comment: @Jelte thank you so much! it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can send the file using the javascript FormData object

Here's a tutorial

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData