# sending a file using ajax and receiving using java

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

Basically I have a form which inside it I have `File` input, now I want to know how to send the choosen file to server using jquery ajax and how to receive the sent file in java EE

```
<div class="browsephoto_div">
<form class="image" method="POST">
    <label class="takeapicture_btn">
        <input type="file" accept=".png, .gif, .jpeg, .jpg" id="imagetoupload" onchange="loadFile(event)" required/>
        <span>Browse</span>
    </label>
</form>
</div>

<script>
var loadFile = function(event) {
var output = document.getElementById('imagetoupload');
alert(output.value);
};
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean "receive the sent file in java EE"? Java EE is the specification only, not the server, and not a particular technology.

Answer (score 0):

what you are trying to achieve is not clear, but i am assuming that you want to select the file and then send it servlet for further processing.

check the link 
[ajax-file-upload-to-a-java-servlet-in-html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914152/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet-and-ajax)
 [ajax-file-upload-to-a-java-servlet-in-html5](http://www.technicaladvices.com/2011/12/10/ajax-file-upload-to-a-java-servlet-in-html5/)
[how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet-and-ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914152/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet-and-ajax)